# AWS QuickSight can't see Athena DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I have a database in Athena, with an external table pointing to a directory in my S3 bucket.  I can query the tables fine in Athena.

When I go to create a new data set in QuickSight, and I select Athena as my source, I don't see my database.

I have followed the instructions here;
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/managing-permissions.html

and here;
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/troubleshoot-connect-athena.html

I also updated the QuickSight S3 policy to ensure QuickSght could List, Read and Write, but still nothing.

[image]

Based on the AWS documentation I feel I should be seeing the DB, but clearly I am missing something?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same issue, after a moment realized that my athena tables are present in eu-west region and I am searching in us-east region in Quicksight.
Please ensure you are searching in the same region where your tables are present.

Comment: That worked, amazing that isn't in any of their guides!

Comment: It solved my problem as well. Thank you :)

Comment: Took me two days to find this! Arghh AWS damm you!

Comment: I have the same problem but QuickSight is not present in ap-south-1 region where athena db is residing. How can i query then?

Comment: I had the same problem - but it was solved by granting a new policy in AWS DataLake Formation using the quicksight role and the database I was attempting to access.

Comment: I am using same role for quicksight and athena, I can query the data in athena but tables not available in quicksight, I verified regions are same, and my role has full permissions on Athena, Glue, Quicksight, any ideas?